# Derivative on summation

Tags: derivatives, summation

Let $f$ be a function of $E_u$:
\begin{align}
f=&\sum_{u=1}^{K_u}\left(2\alpha_u\sqrt{w_u(1+\beta_u)E_u\Theta_u}-\alpha_u^2\left(N_0+\sum_{u'=u+1}^{K_u}E_{u'}\Theta_{u'}+E_u\Theta_u\right)\right)
\end{align},
where $K_u$, $\alpha_u$, $\beta_u$, $w_u$, $\Theta_u$, and $N_0$ are all known. How can we compute $\frac{\partial f}{\partial E_u}?$

Is the answer
\begin{align}
E_u=\frac{w_u(1+\beta_u)\Theta_u}{(\alpha_u\Theta_u)^2},
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
E_u=\frac{\alpha_u^2w_u(1+\beta_u)\Theta_u}{(\sum_{i=1}^{K_u}\alpha_i^2\Theta_i)^2}
\end{align}
My struggling point  is the two summation in the function...
My aim is to get a closed-form expression on $E_u$ when setting $\frac{\partial f}{\partial E_u}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

We use the *linearity* of the partial derivative $\frac{\partial f}{E_u}$, consider all other variables as constant and obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial E_u}
&=\frac{\partial}{\partial E_u}\sum_{u=1}^{K_u}\left(2\alpha_u\sqrt{w_u(1+\beta_u)E_u\Theta_u}-\alpha_u^2\left(N_0+\sum_{u'=u+1}^{K_u}E_{u'}\Theta_{u'}+E_u\Theta_u\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{u=1}^{K_u}\left(2\alpha_u\sqrt{w_u(1+\beta_u)\Theta_u}\,\frac{\partial}{\partial E_u}\left(E_u^{\frac{1}{2}}\right)\right.\\
&\qquad\qquad\left.-\alpha_u^2\left(N_0+\sum_{u'=u+1}^{K_u}E_{u'}\Theta_{u'}+\frac{\partial}{\partial E_u}\left(E_u\right)\Theta_u\right)\right)\\
&=\sum_{u=1}^{K_u}\left(\alpha_u\sqrt{w_u(1+\beta_u)\frac{\Theta_u}{E_u}}-\alpha_u^2\left(N_0+\sum_{u'=u+1}^{K_u}E_{u'}\Theta_{u'}+\Theta_u\right)\right)
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would it be possible to have a closed-form expression on optimal $E_u$ by setting the partial derivative to zero?

Comment: @CharlieNie: You're welcome. Here we have an equation with $K_u$ unknowns. I don't see how to find the optimal $E_u$ without any additional conditions.

Comment: I have a condition on $\sum_{u=1}^{K_u}E_u\le E$, where $E$ is given. But I don't think this will be helpful. Actually I just want to get $\frac{\partial f}{\partial E_u}=0$ and $E_u$ in a closed-form. However, the summation in your answer seems a bit hard to handle if I want a closed-form expression on $E_u$